# python import statements

Tags: python

I've started working on Python for about a month now and I've ran into something I would like to understand better. It's related to imports. So I have a module:
     root.core.connectivity

Now in this module I have defined a class Connectivity. This module also has a `__main__` only for testing purposes(not sure if this makes any differences).

Now if I do:

```
from root.core.connectivity import Connectivity as class_name
```

This works fine, however if I try:

```
import root.core.connectivity.Connectivity as class_name
```

This will fail with:

```
ImportError: No module named Connectivity
```

So my question is, why does it fail and what are the differences between the two statements.

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import` takes a module. `from X import Y` takes a module in X, and any element of that module in Y. `Connectivity` is not a module.

Comment: Note: Since modules are first-class values, you can (and sometimes will) import a module `Y` from a package (or even sub-package) `X` via `from X import Y`. A good reason to import package contents explicitly in `__init__.py` if that isn't a full module in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

Connectivity is a class defined in module, import takes module and when using from-import we can import class of a module.

This link explains it well
http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 0):

root.core.connectivity is a module, while root.core.connectivity.Connectivity is a class. 
To undertand difference beetween import and from .. import you can [use the following link](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/import.html) where you can find:

```
import_stmt ::= "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
| "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
  ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
| "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
  ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
| "from" module "import" "*"
```

E.g you use 'import' with modules and 'from ... import' with identifiers - e.g classes, variables and other modules.

So in your second case you can do the following:

```
import root.core.connectivity as conn
class_name = conn.Connectivity
```