# The difference between 'from pylons import config' and 'import pylons.config'

Tags: python, import, pylons, configuration-files

Im trying to import a company module into my software and I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named config
```

from:

```
from pylons.config import config
```

So obviously, the module that im importing requires pylons.config but cant find it in my virtual environment.

If I go to the terminal and try some Python scripts I can seem to find the config file if I try:

```
from pylons import config
```

but will error if I try:

```
import pylons.config
```

Why is this?

And does anybody how or where I can get:

```
 from pylons.config import config
```

to work. Bearing in mind that I cannot change the code for this module, only mine which is importing it or my own system files.

---

### UPDATE

If anyone finding this page has a similar problem you may find that you are trying to run two modules with different versions of Pylons.

For example, you are creating a login application called **myApp**. You have some Python modules which help with login handling called **pyLogin**.

First you install **pyLogin** with *python setup.py install*. This adds the libraries to your site packages and updates any libraries it depends on, such as SqlAlchemy.

Next you install **myApp** in the same way which again updates libraries and dependencies.

This problem will occur if **pyLogin** and **myApp** are using different versions of Pylons. If **pyLogin** is using Pylons 0.9.6 and **myApp** is using Pylons 1.0 for example, then the **pyLogin** code will be called from **myApp** but it will be running in the wrong Pylons framework and hence will require EITHER **from pylons import config** or **from pylons.config import config**, but will only work with one. If it is using the wrong call for Pylons then you will find yourself with this error message.

So the only solution to this error is to either find earlier or later libraries which use the same Pylons version as your application or to convert your application to the same Pylons version as the libraries you are using.

Comment: Is `config` a class defined in `pylons`? If so, afaik, `from pylons import config` will work but `import pylons.config` won't since you're telling Python to import the **module** pylons.config. With the former form you are telling python to import to the **object** `config` from the module `pylons`.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938277/python-import-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a diffrence between two usages...

`import` loads a Python module into **its own namespace**, while `from` loads a Python module into the **current namespace**.

So, using `from pylons import config` imports config to to your current namespace. But trying to import a **`class`** or **`function`** using `import` is not possible since there is no namespace to keep them... You can only import modules, and use `functions` or `classes` via calling them with their own namespace like

```
import pylons
....
pylons.config #to retreive config
```

[More about import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6372159/257972)