# SyntaxError on import with matplotlib

Tags: python, syntax, plot, matplotlib

This code is giving me a SyntaxError. Not sure what is wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0., 10, 0.1)  
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y);
plt.show();
```

This is the error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-b3d93c2fbfde>", line 2
    from matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I added your actual error message. Nevertheless, some more effort firstable on trying to solve the problem yourself and secondly, describing your problem, and you would have solved it yourself within one minute. -1

Comment: I don't agree with you. I spent a long time getting to know the syntax and stuff. What do you use to run the script. I use Notepad++ for the script and double click on the file to run it.

Comment: For the stuff that you're doing I recommend IPython, especially the new IPython notebook package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python import statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938277/python-import-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second line should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

In addition, note that you don't need a semi-colon terminator in Python.

Also, the `np.linspace` call that you use is wrong - it'll just give you an empty array.  Try the following instead:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=101)
```